# How to get historical data from yahoo finance with base currency

Tags: yahoo, yql, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get historical data from yahoo finance but it gives me only for current date how can i get data with base currency on a specific date.

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.xchange+where+pair+in%28%22PKRUSD%22%2C%22PKRGBP%22%2C%22PKRKWD%22%2C%22PKRSAR%22%29&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no way to get historical exchange rates of two currencies of your choice, however, you can get historical exchange rates from `USD` to any currency in the world. Here is how you get that:

```
SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.historicaldata WHERE symbol = "CCC=X" AND startDate = "YYYY-MM-DD" AND endDate = "YYY-MM-DD"
```

There you choose your currency(CCC) and dates in YYYY-MM-DD format. Example, this will give you the exchange rates from USD to SEK for 2014-10-01 until 2014-10-03:

```
SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.historicaldata WHERE symbol = "SEK=X" AND startDate = "2014-10-02" AND endDate = "2014-10-03"
```

This query will produce the following response:

```
{
 query: {
 count: 3,
 created: "2016-09-10T12:53:42Z",
 lang: "sv-SE",
  results: {
   quote: [
    {
     Symbol: "SEK%3dX",
     Date: "2014-10-03",
     Open: "7.182",
     High: "7.29607",
     Low: "7.182",
     Close: "7.1817",
     Volume: "000",
     Adj_Close: "7.1817"
    },
    {
     Symbol: "SEK%3dX",
     Date: "2014-10-02",
     Open: "7.2151",
     High: "7.2174",
     Low: "7.1723",
     Close: "7.217",
     Volume: "000",
     Adj_Close: "7.217"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

You can always make this twice for two currencies and divide them to get the exhange rates between the two. Example:

```
USD/SEK: 8.5
USD/EUR: 0.85
SEK/EUR = 8.5/0.85 = 10.
```

Hope this answer will be to help.

Comment: what is symbol here? can we add base currency in this query ?

Comment: You can choose whatever currency you want, ( "EUR=x" or "NOK=x" and so on) and they all convert to usd, you need to divide them if you want currency rate between two other currencies besides USD. @Innocent